# Show user email from the user entity to anonymous users

Tags: users

Through views I am trying to show the account email address of any user to any user.

I have checked "Disable SQL rewriting", made sure the view didn't have any permissions, allowed anonymous user to view profiles. After all this it still won't show.

Note: I really don't want to create an additional field that is just syncs up this info just to show it. I want to show the actual field.

Comment: Are you trying to show the email address **of other users** to any user? What's not showing, the email address, or the view?

Comment: That is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the permission so that anonymous users can view the profile of other users? Go to `admin/people/permissions` . See image below
[image]

The view (for anonymous user):

[image]

Comment: Yep, maybe you missed it but I mention that in my original post. "allowed anonymous user to view profiles". User can view every other field but the email address. I am assuming this is by design in drupal core but I should be able to get around it with the sql rewrite as it completely ignores, permissions, roles etc.

Comment: Sorry. Perhaps you can post what your View looks like (the left two columns of the administrative UI for Views) and also let us know if you are using any contextual filter, filter criteria or relationships. This perhaps may help people troubleshoot...

Comment: Also, I just tried it myself. It shows the email of other users fine for anonymous user. No need to disable sql rewriting for me. So, this confirms that this is not a restriction by design in Drupal core.

Comment: interesting. I wonder what I am doing wrong. thanks for your insight and proving me that it can be done. I should have tried on a clean install. instead i jumped to conclusions. i will investigate further.

Comment: Goddammit. I had additional validation on the contextual filter (UID in URL) that was also checking role. removed it and it's working. now I feel like a fool.

Answer (score 1):

Once you done creating views, go to permission tab and check Role

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWUU7.png

in the settings check anonymous, now the user will see the view.

Comment: I have removed and added all roles, permission requirements etc. The view shows but not the actual account email address.