# Fields not appearing in View Rest API unless Bypass group access control

Tags: views

I have a simple content type with lots of fields that I am attempted to expose via the views api. When calling from Postman as an unauthenticated user some of the fields are coming up empty. The view doesn't have any relationships and the field type is Text(long).

When I goto permissions under group and Enable "Bypass group access control" the fields return as expected but obviously I don't want leave this open.

Comment: Do the fields need special roles to view ?

Comment: Related https://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/383534?noredirect=1 and https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/272771/